# Problem with TabHost UI layout

Tags: android, android-tabhost

What I'm trying to do is create a layout like this:

```
       +--------+ 
Search |EditText| [Button]
       +--------+

+---------+
|Tab 1    |---------+
|         |Tab 2    |
|---------+---------+-----------------+
| ListView Item 1                     |
| ListView Item 2                     |
| ListView Item 3                     |
| ListView Item 4                     |
| ListView Item 5                     |
| ListView Item 6                     |
| ListView Item 7                     |
| ListView Item 8                     |
| ListView Item 9                     |
| ListView Item 10                    |
+-------------------------------------+
```

So that's a TextView saying 'Search', an EditText and a button.

Then below it the tabs - Tab 1 has a ListView, Tab 2 some other stuff. I can get a simple TabHost setup with two tabs working fine but can't get the above to lay out properly.

The issue is that that it installs and runs fine - just the layout is wrong. I've tried weighted views and so on but I can't get things to position as per the ASCII diagram above.

I'd create the UI in the Eclipse designer and check the XML from that, except the designer doesn't work with TabHost. And DroidDraw doesn't seem to know about TabHost.

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/TabHost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/SearchTextView"
                android:text="Search"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="10">
            </TextView>

            <EditText 
                android:text="@+id/SearchEditText" 
                android:id="@+id/SearchEditText" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_weight="10">
            </EditText>

            <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="10"/>

            <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="70">

                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/Tab1ListLayout" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                </LinearLayout>     

                <Button android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="Tab 2 button"/>

            </FrameLayout>      
        </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

... and here's the Activity:

```
    public class tabtest extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabs = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.TabHost);
        tabs.setup();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabs.newTabSpec("tag1");
        spec.setContent(R.id.Tab1ListLayout);
        spec.setIndicator("Tab 1");
        tabs.addTab(spec);
        spec=tabs.newTabSpec("tag2");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        spec.setIndicator("Tab 2");
        tabs.addTab(spec);

        EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.SearchEditText);
        et.setText("Some text.");

    }
```

Comment: Post the code in your question so that others can see what you have done until now and give answers based on it.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest Eclipse designer or AndroidDraw for designing tabs. Better do it manually in xml or in your code.
As primalpop said, please specify what exactly your difficulty is ("tabs working fine but can't get the above to lay out properly"). Is it about how to apply different heights/margin/padding for tab1/2?

Comment: Mathias - I mentioned Eclipse/DroidDraw in the sense that I couldn't even use those to check generated XML for what it *should* look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to review basics such ["layout resources"](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html) and ["declaring layout"](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html).

See [layout tricks](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html) for "weight" linear layout trick. Possible solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/SearchTextView"
                android:text="Search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>

            <EditText 
                android:text="@+id/SearchEditText" 
                android:id="@+id/SearchEditText" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true">
            </EditText>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"/>
             <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/Tab1ListLayout" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </LinearLayout>     

            <Button android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tab 2 button"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: It was fairly obvious from the Hierarchy Viewer what was wrong - I didn't know about that tool.